# Arduino: float function returns inf

Tags: arduino, floating-point, least-squares, divide-by-zero

I have a function (shown below) that I need some advice on. The function returns the slope of a line which is fit (via the least squares method) to n data points. To give you a context, my project is a barometric pressure based altimeter which uses this function to determine velocity based on the n most recent altitude-time pairs. These altitude-time pairs are stored in 2 global arrays(`times[]` and `alts[]`).

My problem is not that this method doesn't work. It usually does. But sometimes I will run the altimeter and this function will return the value `'inf'` interspersed with a bunch of other wrong values (I have also seen 'NaN' but that is more rare). There are a few areas of suspicion I have at this point but I would like a fresh perspective. Here is some further contextual information that may or may not be of use:

- I am using interrupts for a quadrature encoder
- The `times[]` array is of type `unsigned long`
- The `alts[]` array is of type `float`
- `n` is a `const int`, in this case `n = 9`
- On the ATMEGA328 a `double` is the same as a `float`.. [Arduino-double](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double)

  ```
  float velF() { // uses the last n data points, fits a line to them, 
                 // and uses the slope of that line as the velocity at that moment
       float sumTY = 0, sumT = 0, sumY = 0, sumT2 = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           sumTY += (float)times[i] * alts[i] / 1000;
           sumT += (float)times[i] / 1000;
           sumY += alts[i];
           sumT2 += (float)times[i] * times[i] / 1000000;
       }
       return (n*sumTY - sumT*sumY) / (n*sumT2 - sumT*sumT);
  }
  ```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a division there. Have you checked the denominator for zero?

Comment: When OP says *"sometimes I will run the altimeter and this function will return the value 'inf' interspersed with a bunch of other wrong values"* are you talking of the altimeter interface?

Comment: Here is some more info that may help: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=46912.0           http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: Eugene, That is my first thought given that inf can result from a division by 0. During 'normal' operation, however, that denominator should not be 0.

Comment: Well check it, then you can be sure.

Comment: Weather, yes. When this function is run iteratively it returns inf every few values

Comment: I am sure that the denominator is not 0 when it is working properly. When it does fail, it doesn't fail immediately. The instances when it has failed have been when I have run the sketch for > a minute or so. This led me to suspect an overflow or a memory issue. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Well then maybe the memory overflow can cause that the denominator becomes 0.

Comment: @Ben Stringer I don't think you understood: insert some code to see if the denominator **is** zero, or close to it, to dispel your assumptions about what it "should be". If that fails, then the problem lies somewhere else, or the algorithm is incorrect. So dump the array contents and examine them when it happens.

Comment: If the division yields `inf` then there are only four possibilities: (1) the dividend is `inf`; (2) the divisor is 0; (3) the compiler produced incorrect code; or (4) the hardware is broken.  The last two of those are unlikely.  The first does not appear consistent with the code.  That leaves a zero divisor as the most likely explanation.

Comment: Note that your divisor will definitely be `0` if `n` is 1, or if all the times but one are 0.

Comment: The divisor will also be zero if all the `times[]` elements you consider are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Code is certainly performing division by zero.

For a variety of reasons, `n*sumT2 - sumT*sumT` will be zero. [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621398/arduino-float-function-returns-inf/37623177#comment62726571_37621398)  In most of these cases, the top (dividend) of the division will also be zero and a return value of zero would be acceptable.

```
float velF(void) {
     float sumTY = 0, sumT = 0, sumY = 0, sumT2 = 0;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {

         // insure values are reasoable
         assert(alts[i]  >= ALT_MIN  && alts[i]  <= ALT_MAX);
         assert(times[i] >= TIME_MIN && times[i] <= TIME_MAX);

         sumTY += (float)times[i] * alts[i] / 1000;
         sumT += (float)times[i] / 1000;
         sumY += alts[i];
         sumT2 += (float)times[i] * times[i] / 1000000;
     }

     float d = n*sumT2 - sumT*sumT;
     if (d == 0) return 0;
     return (n*sumTY - sumT*sumY) / d;
}
```

Side note: could factor out the division for improved accuracy and speed.  Suggest performing the last calculation as `double`.

```
float velF(void) {
     float sumTY = 0, sumT = 0, sumY = 0, sumT2 = 0;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         float tf = (float) times[i];
         sumTY += tf * alts[i];
         sumT += tf;
         sumY += alts[i];
         sumT2 += tf * tf;
     }

     double nd = n; 
     double sumTd = sumT; 
     double d = nd*sumT2 - sumTd*sumTd;
     if (d == 0) return 0;
     return (nd*sumTY - sumTd*sumY)*1000 / d;
}
```

Comment: I have a high level of confidence that it is performing a division by zero. @chux's suggestion will be an excellent way of isolating the denominator and confirming this theory with some good old Serial.print() debugging. That will allow me to approach the answer to the real question which is: why does this function work sometimes but not others? I simply cannot 'toss out' values that return 'inf'. The fact that the program believes my velocity to be infinitely large is an indication of a more buried problem. I will be sure to post an answer when I find it!

Comment: Side note on the side note: I was under the impression that on the ATMEGA328 a double was the same as a float?  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double

Comment: @Ben Stringer   My `double` suggestion was for general platforms.  Appears to have no benefit on yours.

Comment: I tested it and the code is performing a division by 0, But it still shouldn't be! I have never seen anything like it. When the denominator went to 0, I had it print out the variables sumT and sumT2 to see if the denominator would work out to 0. But it did not. It should have been something like 13 or 14 but yet it still reported a 0! Any thoughts on this new information?

Comment: @Ben Stringer 1) ".. is performing a division by 0, But it still shouldn't be" --> Why not? What are the values of the inputs? 2) " had it print out the variables" --> what format did you use `"%f"` or `"%e"`?  Suggest  `"%e"`.  3) Are you using a variation of this answer's code?